# Add a method to a custom type

Tags: scala, slick

Apologies if the wording of this question is wrong, I'm very new to Scala and strongly-typed languages.

Basically I'm using Slick and the code generator outputs the following lines for each table (VideoCaptions table in this case):

```
type VideoCaptionsRow = HCons[Int,HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[Boolean],HCons[Option[Boolean],HCons[Option[String],HCons[java.sql.Timestamp,HCons[Int,HCons[Option[String],HNil]]]]]]]]
/** Constructor for VideoCaptionsRow providing default values if available in the database schema. */
def VideoCaptionsRow(id: Int, audioLanguage: Option[String] = None, hasCaptionFile: Option[Boolean] = Some(false), isDeleted: Option[Boolean] = Some(false), language: Option[String] = None, lastModified: java.sql.Timestamp, videoId: Int, regions: Option[String]): VideoCaptionsRow = {
  id :: audioLanguage :: hasCaptionFile :: isDeleted :: language :: lastModified :: videoId :: regions :: HNil
}
```

When I perform a query in slick on the VideoCaptions table I get back an object of type VideoCaptionsRow (which is apparently shorthand for the giant HCons type). I want to add a method to the VideoCaptionsRow object so that I can call it on query result rows. Is there a way to change the type definition so that it isn't just a shorthand for the HCons type, but also includes an extra method while remaining usable by Slick internally?

Comment: Have you checked their [`code generation`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/code-generation.html) page?  I don't see any mention of rows there or in the scaladocs, or code example.  What about `<>` [mapping](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/migration.html#mapped-tables) and making a case class that has a companion object with useful functions instead( since you don't appear to have > 22 columns ).  (I haven't used 2.0 yet, so I am wondering if the `<>` mapping would "force" the row type for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an implicit class to extend the functionality in your own code. No need to change the code generator.

```
implicit class VideoCaptionsRowExtensions(row: VideoCaptionsRow){
  def foo = row(0) // <- e.g. alias the first HList entry as def foo, or compute something
}
VideoCaptions.filter(...).run.map(_.foo) // access new member `foo`
```